# Can the distance between $3$ points be worked out given their magnetic bearings?

Tags: trigonometry, triangulation

I have 3 moving points which I want to find the distance between.

Each point transmits radio waves which the others receive. At each point the field strength of the transmitted wave from the other two points can be found and this field strength can be roughly correlated to a distance.

So essentially I will have a triangle and have $2$ rough estimates of the length of each side. I will be able to use these distances + the headings to work out $2$ more estimations of each length and then try and outrule anomalous data by weighting values which are closer together.

If it was possible to work out the distance using the headings alone the results would become much more accurate however I cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: Is this on a sphere or in a plane?

Comment: On a flat plane this is impossible (without the approximate distance information) because you can scale the size of the triangle without any changes to the bearings. On the surface of Earth the situation is better, because the deviation of the sum of the angles from 180 degrees gives you some indication of the size of the triangle.

Comment: 3 points moving around a 2D plane

Comment: I'm assuming a 2D plane as the points won't be too far away from each other (<20m) but technically they are on the globe's surface, I just don't know if there would be enough deviation of the sum of angles?

Comment: You're right. At that scale the demands on the accuracy of the bearings would be unbearably high for the curvature of the Earth's surface to come to your aid.

Comment: Oh well. Was worth a try. Thanks for helping and letting me continue to be lazy and not have to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Jyrki Lahtonen in the comments:

On a flat plane it is impossible to work out the distance using the magnetic bearings alone. The reason is that you can scale the size of the triangle without any changes to the bearings. On the surface of Earth the situation is better, because the deviation of the sum of the angles from 180 degrees gives you some indication of the size of the triangle. However, this does not come into play on the scale of ~20 m.